# How do you interpret WAKEUP_STAT and WAKEUP_INTx_PEND in exynos SoC kmsg?

Tags: android, linux-kernel, power-management

I am seeing the following lines in kmsg when my Galaxy S2 device wakes up from suspend. I understand that this is supposed to tell me which interrupts are pending but I can't find a way to figure out which:

```
<1>[40470.716887] PM: SLEEP
<6>[40681.900179] WAKEUP_STAT: 0x80000001
<6>[40681.900179] WAKEUP_INTx_PEND: 0x0, 0x0, 0x20, 0x0

<6>[ 1099.481006] WAKEUP_STAT: 0x80000001
<6>[ 1099.481006] WAKEUP_INTx_PEND: 0x0, 0x2, 0x0, 0x0
```

Answer (score 3):

I think that 0,0,0x20,0 is Wake On LAN, but I don't know what 0,2,0,0 is.

If you look a bit further down from the `WAKEUP_INTx_PEND` prints you should see a print that starts with `wakeup wake lock:` where you get the name of the wake lock.

Comment: Thanks for answering. That's the line you referred to after the 0,2,0,0:

<6>[  142.607377] wakeup wake lock: sec-battery-monitor


Is there a way to find out that? I tried following the kernel code but it got me to a dead end.